# How to disable headers in php-cgi response

Tags: php, cgi

I have php-cgi running on my machine. When my server sends a request to php-cgi, the response includes headers (content-type & X-Powered-By) + the php file output.

Is it possible to disable the headers in the response? I've tried "-q" which only works when I don't combine that option with -b. I need a solution that works with -b

Comment: If we're talking about PHP specific headers have you tried to use `header_remove` in your scripts?

Comment: I dont want to add a specific line to each and every php file, I was hoping for a setting that is applied to all. As -q

Comment: Regarding the `X-Powered-By` you have a ini setting: `expose_php`. By the looks of it, the `default_mimetype` setting might work to disable the `Content-type` header, give it a try (reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Thanks brother. This will work fine.